# How to test web-apps on mobile for free without wlan?

Tags: testing, web-applications, mobile, usability, emulation

I tried  GNUBOX which use bluetooth to connect to my computer then to the internet. It's very painful to set up (under windows more than under linux, but it's still painful, it works 1 time on 3).

I own a Nokia 6630 so there is no WLAN support. Is there any emulator? I'd need to know something like max width, max height etc... usability in general, any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound silly but you could consider getting a mobile tariff with unlimited data. In most European countries these are now available and are not too expensive.

I don't believe you would get a solid experience from any emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're only limiting to the 6630 or not...if not, Opera Mini has a [free simulator](http://www.operamini.com/demo/).

If you find yourself needing to do more testing on multiple devices, there's always [Device Anywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/)...but it definitely does not meet your requirement for free.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a data cable and IP pass through?

Since the 6630 is a Symbian phone, you should be able to use GNUbox to handle the connection. See http://xan.dnsalias.org/gnubox/

Answer (score 0):

Keynote's MITE just launched a free version for content testing; it includes the 6630 along with more than 1600 other profiles and 11,000 user agent strings.  You can access via LAN get the protocol details.